# history.js: how to manage back button

Tags: jquery, html, back, history.js

in html5 history api, using history.js i am trying to implement an ajax navigation,using jquery to append html contents to a container div.

It works changing pages, but when i push the back button in the browser it changes only the usr in the address bar, but the page remains the same.

```
/* SETUP HISTORY JS */
var History = window.History;
var State = History.getState();

// Log Initial State
//History.log('initial:', State.data, State.title, State.url);

// Bind to State Change
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
    var State = History.getState();
});
/* END SETUP HISTORY JS */
```

Clicking on the links i define link_title_ link_href and the ajaxurl of the file, so i get its content in ajax and i update history:

```
// CHANGING THE PAGES
$.get(''+ajax_url,function(data) {
    $('#container').append(''+data); //LOAD THE PAGE
    History.pushState({state:''+link_href,rand:Math.random()}, link_title, link_href);
}
```

i woould like to refresh the #container content with the old html value, do i need to get the state and perform another get() call?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/854622

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting your ajax call Bind State Change

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
var State = History.getState();
//Do ajax call here...
});
```

That should keep the content so when you do navigate forward or back the container will have the old values.